# How do I access a MinIO storage bucket from a Jupyter Pyspark notebook?

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have instances of MinIO and Jupyter Pyspark notebook running locally on separate docker containers. I am able to use the minio Python package to view buckets and objects in MinIO, however when I try to load a parquet from a bucket using Pyspark I get the below:

Code:

```
salesDF_path = 's3a://{}:{}/data/sales/example.parquet'.format(host, port)
df = spark.read.load(salesDF_path)
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.load.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 30 more
```

I'm trying to write a script that spins up these containers, runs some tests, then tears them down. Is there some configuration that I need to include somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow next steps:

#### relevant aws jars

Make sure you have installed following `jars`:

- [aws-java-sdk](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar)
- [hadoop-aws](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.3/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar)

You can run your `pyspark` application something like:

`pyspark --jars "aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar,hadoop-aws-2.7.3`
(or from a docker `CMD`)

#### Inside the notebook, configure 'hadoop configuration'

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "access_key")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "secret_key")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.proxy.host", "minio")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "minio")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.proxy.port", "9000")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
```

Please check [s3a client configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#General_S3A_Client_configuration) to a full list of params

Now should be able to query data from `minio`, for example:

`sc.textFile("s3a://<file path>")`

Answer (score 0):

Could you show how you have installed Spark and initialized it? It looks like you have to download the Java library for `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`. Can you make sure you have the `hadoop-aws` and `aws-java-sdk` JARS installed? I use http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.3/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar and  http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar.

Answer (score 0):

See this comment here: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/272#issuecomment-244278586

Specifically:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.34,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.6.0,com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0 pyspark-shell'
```

This helped get rid of that class not found error